# Simple explanation of the many functional uses of 'should'?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, should

> [[User John Lawler]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209850/putative-should-what-time-does-it-express?lq=1#comment446143_209857): So how many named special cases of each modal verb are there, in toto? There's
>   1. subjunctive **should**, and
>   2. mandative **should**, and
>   3. [putative **should**](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/224111/50720), at least;
>   and I s[up]pose 4. *Should we?* is suggestive **should**, and
>   5. *Shouldn't we?* is `tag **should**`, and I can think of a lot more.

I ask about only operative uses of this modal verb including literary and formal usage,  but please omit anything obsolete. I'm trying to classify them and learn the formal terms describing each.
Are there any apt others in addition to the ones above? (I added the enumeration below)

1. What's 'subjunctive **should**'?  Whenever **should** is conjugated in the subjunctive mood?
5. What's a `tag **should**` ?
6. Where does  **should/would**  feature? What's it called? This **should** is detailed in  [point 3 under 'Usage Notes' on page  1 of 2](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/shouldgloss.htm) or [the last para herein](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/10078/50720) or ["should like to" vs. "would like to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102153/50720).

Comment: The conclusion of John Lawler's original comment seems to be that pursuing these distinctions offers very little value.

Comment: I think I would agree with that. Collecting "meanings" for modal auxiliaries is a losing game. Classifying them doesn't tell you how to recognize or describe them. As the OED and Cerberus demonstrate.

Comment: As Cerberus has demonstrated, the answer is 41³⁄₇ meanings. How does that help you?

Comment: To all users above: Thank you for your comments. I now realise that my question doesn't help as I had intended, so I ought to have delivered a more helpful question, because all these meanings of **should** truly confuse me. What should've I asked? Would you please help me to improve my question and to resolve my confusion?

Comment: So your trouble is that *should* is used in diverse ways, and this confuses you?  This really is true of all modals. My recommendation is that you try to learn them the way a native speaker learns them instead of trying to tally and classify them all.

Comment: @tchrist It seems that **should** involves many more definitions than usual, so yes. Would you please advise how a native speaker would learn them?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Read a lot. Listen to people talking. Eventually it all kinda falls into place and you don’t even notice that it is being used in so many different ways, because your mind will come to encompass the polysemic superposition without thinking anything of it.

Comment: @tchrist My goal for today will be to nonchalantly drop "polysemic superposition" into conversation.

Comment: @Law, Heed tchrist, he knows whereof he speaks. The only way to grok *should* (or any other construction) is through repeated exposure. That is: practice. Memorizing dictionary entries is not a viable alternative. Plus, one major benefit of the exposure approach is it will, by definition, teach you the most common and therefore useful and relevant meanings first; it will underweight less common and therefore less relevant senses, and exclude obsolete senses altogether. As to "*What should've I asked?*", I can only think of [this quote from Charles Babbage](http://j.mp/1LhzOIV).

Comment: @DanBron Thank you as ever. I've updated and tried to improve my OP, because it is bootless to try to all > 40 definitions. Any other advice to improve this OP?

Answer (score 8):

The Oxford English Dictionary, under *shall*, describes 11 different special uses of *should* (#12–23), some of which obsolete, but most having several sub-uses. And this excludes many of the regular uses of *should* as the ordinary past tense of *shall*, some of which are included in #24–29.

> ### The past tense *should* with temporal function.
>
> 12. †Expressing a former obligation or necessity: = ‘was bound to’, ‘had to’. *Obs*.
> 13. †In statements of what was formerly intended or settled to take place; = ‘was to’, or (contextually) ‘was about to’. *Obs*.
> 14. Used in indirect reported utterances, or other statements relating to past time, where *shall* would be used if the time referred to were present.
>
>     a. corresponding to *shall* in sense 5, 6, or 7.
>
>     b. corresponding to *shall* in sense 8.
>
>     Here *should* is the auxiliary of the ‘anterior future’ or ‘future in the past’ tense. With perf. inf. it forms the ‘anterior future perfect’ or ‘future perfect in the past’.
>
>     c. in hypothetical, temporal, and final clauses, and relative clauses with hypothetical or final implication. (Cf. 10.)
>
>     d. In noun-clause dependent on expressions of willing, desiring, commanding, requesting, etc. (in the pa. tense). Similarly (esp. with the verb *want*) in the pres. tense (*colloq*., orig. and chiefly *U.S.* and in representations of Jewish speech). (Cf. 11 and 22a.)
>
>     e. In statements of a former likelihood, unlikelihood, expectation, hope, fear, etc.
>
>     In present usage the rules for the choice of the auxiliary are the same as apply to the future tense (see 8). Until the middle of the 19th c., however, should was common in this use in the second and third persons, where would is now normal.
>
>     f. In statements of what habitually occurred. (Cf. sense 9.) Now *rare* (? *dial*.).
> 15. a. Forming with the inf. a substitute for the pa. tense ind. (or, with perf. inf., for the pluperf.) in the oblique report of another's statement in order to imply that the speaker does not commit himself to the truth of the alleged fact. (The perf. inf. was often substituted for the pres. inf. merely in order to express the notion of past time more unambiguously. *Obs*. exc. *dial*.
>
>     The corresponding use of *shall* (= G. *soll*, ‘is said to’) is not evidenced in Eng., the OE. instances alleged by Bosw.–Toller having apparently a different meaning.
>
>     ¶b. with omission of the *have* of the perf. inf.
> 16. In indirect question relating to a past matter of fact. *Obs*. exc. *arch*.
>
>     Present usage prefers the pa. tense or perf.; when the notion of uncertainty is emphasized, *might* or *could* is used instead of the earlier *should*.
> 17. In questions introduced by *who, whom, what*, and followed by *but*, serving to express the unexpectedness of some past occurrence.
>
> ### The past tense *should* with modal function.
>
> As with other auxiliaries, the pa. tense (orig. subjunctive) of *shall* is often used to express, not a reference to past time, but a modal qualification of the notion expressed by the present tense. Where in addition the notion of past time is to be expressed, this can often be effected by the use of the perf. instead of the pres. inf. (though sometimes this produces ambiguity); the temporal notion may however be merely contextually implied, and in that case the pa. tense has the appearance of having both functions (temporal and modal) at once.
>
> 18. a. In statements of duty, obligation, or propriety (originally, as applicable to hypothetical conditions not regarded as real). Also, in statements of expectation, likelihood, prediction, etc.
>
>     This conditional form of expression was from an early period substituted for the unconditional shall in sense 2, and in mod.Eng. the pres. tense in this use is obs., and should = ought to.
>
>     ¶with omission of *have* in perf. inf.
>
>     b. ***<sub><sup>SHOULD BE</sup></sub>***: ought according to appearances to be, presumably is. Also, ought according to expectation to be, presumably will be (cf. sense 18a).
>
>     c. ***<sub><sup>YOU SHOULD HEAR</sup></sub>, <sub><sup>SEE</sup></sub>*** = I wish you could hear, if only you could hear, etc.
>
>     d. Used ironically, expressing the inappropriateness or unlikeliness of the action advocated or state envisaged, as *I **<sub><sup>SHOULD WORRY</sup></sub>***, there is no reason for me to worry, I am not worried. *colloq*. (orig. a Yiddishism).
> 19. In the apodosis of a hypothetical proposition (expressed or implied), indicating that the supposition, and therefore its consequence, is unreal.
>
>     a. Where *shall* (in sense 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9) would be used if the hypothesis were accepted.
>
>     b. When the pres. tense of the principal vb. would be used if the hypothesis were accepted. (Where the pa. tense or the perf. would be used, *should* is followed by the perf. inf.)
>
>     In this use the combination of *should* with inf. forms a periphrastic past subjunctive: thus ‘I should be’ = the archaic ‘I were’. Similarly with perf. inf.: ‘Then I should have been’ = ‘then had I been’.
>
>     The choice between *should* and *would* follows the same rules as that between *shall* and *will* as future auxiliaries, except that should must sometimes be avoided on account of liability to be misinterpreted as = ‘ought to’ (sense 18). In present Eng. *should* occurs mainly in the first person; in the other persons it follows the rule for *shall* in 8 c, d.
>
>     ¶with omission of *have* in perf. inf.
>
>     c. With verbs of liking, preference, etc., *should* in the first person (and interrogatively in the second) is regarded as more correct than *would*, though this is often used.
>
>     In the third person *should* is used only in indirect speech (when *he* represents *I*); uses like quot. 1862 are abnormal.
>
>     The forms *I should have liked to (see)* and *I should like to have (seen)* are alternative ways of adding the temporal notion to the modal sense of *should*. Another form, sometimes met with, but certainly faulty, is *I should have liked to have (seen)*.
>
>     d. The original conditional notion is obscured in the phrases ***<sub><sup>IT SHOULD SEEM</sup></sub>*** (see <sub><sup>**SEEM**</sup></sub> *v.* 7f); one should think (now somewhat *arch*. and perh. sometimes interpreted in the sense of 18). Similarly *I **<sub><sup>SHOULD THINK</sup></sub>*** (***<sub><sup>SUPPOSE</sup></sub>***, etc.) = ‘I am inclined to think (suppose, etc.)’; also *colloq*. as a strong affirmation in reply to a tentative suggestion, e.g. ‘I should (rather) think he *did* object’.
>
>     In the last phrase (as used idiomatically), *would* is never substituted; in the second person the phrase is used only in questions, and in the third person only in oblique narration.
>
>     †e. ***<sub><sup>SHOULD HAVE BEEN</sup></sub>*** = ‘would have had to be’: see 3b. (In quot. with omission of *have*.)
>
>     f. *I **<sub><sup>SHOULD</sup></sub>*** (***<sub><sup>DO</sup></sub>*** so and so): orig. with expressed or understood protasis ‘if I were you’, but in mod. colloquial language often used loosely = ‘I would advise you to (do, etc.)’.
> 20. In a hypothetical clause expressing a rejected supposition.
>
>     †a. Where *should* has notional force = ‘were obliged to’, ‘must’, ‘were about to’. Often with ellipsis of *if* after *as*. *Obs*.
>
>     With the use as in quot. 1530 cf. the modern ‘as if his heart would break’.
>
>     b. Where the future tense (or the present with future import) would be used if the supposition were entertained. (With pa. tense subjunctive, usually *should* or *would*, also *could, might*, arch. *were*, etc., in the apodosis. Cf. 21.) Now somewhat *rare*, mod. usage preferring *were to*.
>
>     †c. With reference to the past (e.g. ‘if he should have done’ = if he had done). *Obs*.
>
>     d. In relative clause with hypothetical import.
>
>     e. as ***<sub><sup>WHO SHOULD SAY</sup></sub>*** [cf. F. *comme qui dirait*] = as much as to say. *arch*. Also †***<sub><sup>AS IF WE WOULD SAY</sup></sub>*** (***<sub><sup>SHOULD HAVE SAID</sup></sub>***).
> 21. a. In a hypothetical clause relating to the future, *should* takes the place of *shall* (indicative or subjunctive), or of the equivalent use of the present tense, when the supposition, though entertained as possible, is viewed as less likely or less welcome than some alternative. (With future, future perf., or imperative in the apodosis.)
>
>     b. Similarly, with perf. inf., in a hypothetical clause relating to what may have happened in the past.
> 22. In a noun-clause (normally introduced by *that*).
>
>     a. In dependence on expressions of will, desire, command, advice, request.
>
>     Where the verb of the governing clause is in the pa. tense, this use is indistinguishable from that treated in 14d.
>
>     The substitution of *should* for the earlier *shall* (itself a periphrastic substitute for the more primitive use of the pres. subjunctive: see 11a) may have arisen from instances in which the governing vb. was in the modal pa. tense (as in quots. c1200, 1340).
>
>     b. In statements relating to the necessity, justice, propriety, etc. of something contemplated as future, or as an abstract supposition.
>
>     c. In expressions of surprise or its absence, approval or disapproval, of some present or past fact.
>
>     ¶with omission of *have* in the perf. inf.
>
>     d. In clause dependent on sentence (negative, interrogative, or hypothetical) expressing possibility, probability, or expectation.
>
>     Cf. ‘Is it possible that he should do this?’ with ‘It is possible that he may do this’. Similarly, ‘It is unlikely that he should have been there’, but ‘It is likely that he was (or may have been) there’.
>
>     e. In clause (now almost always with *lest*) expressing the object of fear or precaution.
> 23. In special interrogative uses.
>
>     a. In questions introduced by *why* (or equivalent word), implying the speaker's inability to conceive any reason or justification for something actual or contemplated, or any ground for believing something to be fact.
>
>     b. In questions introduced by *how*, implying that the speaker regards something as impossible or inadmissible.
>
>     †c. In questions relating to meaning, cause, or reason, the form with *should* was formerly often substituted for an indicative tense. *Obs*.
>
> ### Elliptical and quasi-elliptical uses
>
> 24. With ellipsis of verb of motion: = ‘shall go’. Now *arch*.
>
>     The use is common in OHG. and OS., and in later HG., LG., and Du. In the mod. Scandinavian langs. it is also common, and instances occur in MSw.
> 25. †In questions, ***<sub><sup>WHAT SHALL</sup></sub>*** = ‘what shall (it) profit’, ‘what good shall (I) do’. *Obs*. (*rare* after OE.).
> 26. †With the sense ‘is due’, ‘is proper’, ‘is to be given or applied’. *Obs*. Cf. G. soll.
> 27. a. With ellipsis of active infinitive to be supplied from the context.
> 28. †a. With ellipsis of do (not occurring in the context). *Obs. rare.*
>
>     The place of the inf. is sometimes supplied by *that* or *so* placed at the beginning of the sentence.
>
>     The construction may be regarded as an ellipsis of *do*. It is distinct from the use (belonging to 27) in which so has the sense of ‘thus’, ‘likewise’, or ‘also’; in the latter there is usually inversion, as *so shall I*.
> 29. †With ellipsis of be or passive inf., or with *so* in place of this (where the preceding context *has is, was*, etc.). *Obs*.

Image of OED online from Chrome on Windows7 showing formatting (can be removed).
That's what I see for *shall 20.e* (my yellow highlighting)
[image]

Comment: Why the small-caps? OED don't do small-caps for those uses they only use it for names of authors (and links to other words).

Comment: @Frank Actually, yes they do. Even if you have no subscription, go to the OED’s online site and look at the word of the day and the recent entries under it, all of which require no subscription. You'll see them using small caps for exactly these things that are in the posting.

Comment: @tchrist Cerberus: Thank you for your comment. I wrongly used 'mock' in an old post and instead had intended to mean whether the earlier comments meant to imply that my question was unhelpful. I admit that I posed a bad question so have tried to recast it, but I shall peruse this. I apologise for any offense.

Comment: @tchrist - The online OED (that I see) uses bold-italic normal cased letters where you've used small-caps. Maybe it's a browser difference, just wondered. I've added an image of what it looks like on Windows7/Chrome - feel free to remove the image any time. This should probably be in meta really.

Answer (score 5):

1. *Subjunctive* meaning of should:

> ***Should*** you get lost in Mexico, remember *el baño* means bathroom.

2. *Mandative* (AKA Obligatory)meaning of should:

> You ***should*** eat your vegetables!

3. *Putative* meaning of should:

> It struck us as funny that you ***should*** ask this question.

4. *Suggestive* meaning of should:

> The others brought a flashlight along. ***Should*** we?

5. *Tag* meaning of should:

> He shouldn't have another drink. ***Should*** he?

These subtle modal auxiliary meanings of *should* carry on *ad nauseam*!

6. Both *should* and *would* have been doing **so much** modal auxiliary work for **so long** in English that we often find them working together and doing each others jobs.