# What's the meaning of "you should worry"?

Tags: humor, irony

According to Cambridge Dictionary,

> they should worry! (humorous) ​
>
> said about or to someone who clearly has no need to worry:
>
> She should worry! She hasn't a problem in the world.

How come? Is it ironic? Could you please give another example?

Comment: The OED quote in Cerberus's answer to the following question seems to discuss this example a bit: [Simple explanation of the many functional uses of 'should'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224118)

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in the topic linked in the comments ([The many functional uses of "should"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224118/simple-explanation-of-the-many-functional-uses-of-should)), but it is a minor subset of the larger issues covered there. In particular, from the OED quote section,

> d. Used ironically, expressing the inappropriateness or unlikeliness of the action advocated or state envisaged, as I SHOULD WORRY, there is no reason for me to worry, I am not worried. colloq. (orig. a Yiddishism).

The use can be ironic or sarcastic. It is colloquial and /or dialectic, rather than literal.