# Need help with this specific use of "Should"

Tags: word-usage, should

"We will retain his rights should he wish to be moved elsewhere at a later date"

What are the rules with using "should" like that? should he wish to and so on.

Because it looks weird. but I know it's correct as it's not the first time I'm seeing "should" being used like that.

thank you

Comment: It means *in the event that* but is used with the bare infinitive, so *should he wish* = *in the event that he wishes*.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224118/simple-explanation-of-the-many-functional-uses-of-should

Comment: It's quite a common **conditional** construction. "Should he wish to be moved elsewhere at a later date" is the protasis consisting of a conditional clause, where the special conditional "should" triggers inversion ("he should ~ should he"). It's the equivalent of "if he should wish to be moved elsewhere ...".