# Meaning of should and would

Tags: meaning

Here's a text:
 'I'm going out now. Is it cold out?' 'Yes, I should wear a coat.'
It means 'If I were you, I would wear a coat'.
So my question is can I just say 'Yes, I would wear a coat'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. In 19th century English, for instance, it's very common to say "I should" where moderns just use "I would".

Comment: I [should like to](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102153/should-like-to-vs-would-like-to) point out that this is not restricted to 19th century English—it’s still relatively commonly heard in (formal) British English, and there are still people who prefer “shall/should” in the first person singular vs. “will/would” in other persons.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, definitely, thanks for clarifying; by saying it was very common back then I didn't mean to say it's ungrammatical now. :)